# Customizing Autofac in Azure mobile app results in 'No service registered for ITableControllerConfigProvider type' exception

Tags: autofac, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to customize an Azure Web app application that was created with Visual Studio.  I've added an AccountsController to help with user registration using the Owin membership tables.  I want to add Owin to the site, so I'm customizing the WebApiConfig.cs file with this method:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
       // Use this class to set configuration options for your mobile service
       var options = new ConfigOptions();

       var configBuilder = new ConfigBuilder(options, (configuration, builder) =>
       {
           var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
           var file = FileHelper.GetLoggingConfigFile(executingAssembly);

           // startup the logging
           _logger = new Logger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, file);

           //builder.RegisterInstance(new CustomOwinAppBuilder(configuration))
           //                            .As<IOwinAppBuilder>();

           //configure the Autofac IoC container
           AutofacBuilder.Configure(executingAssembly, _logger, builder, new MvcModule(),
               new TaskModule());

       });

       var defaultConfig = ServiceConfig.Initialize(configBuilder);

       // Make sure this is after ServiceConfig.Initialize
       // Otherwise ServiceConfig.Initialize will overwrite your changes
       StartupOwinAppBuilder.Initialize(app =>
       {
           // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
           app.CreatePerOwinContext(TrainMobileContext.Create);
           app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

           // app.UseFacebookAuthentication("", "");
       });

       defaultConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );

       // To display errors in the browser during development, uncomment the following
       // line. Comment it out again when you deploy your service for production use.
       // config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

       Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());
   }
```

The AutofacBuilder handles a lot of the registration with statements like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<RepositoryProvider>().As<IRepositoryProvider>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
       builder.RegisterType<DataManager>().As<IDataManager>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
       builder.RegisterType<Logger>().As<ILogger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();          

       // new TrainMobileUserStore(context.Get<SpaceLinxContext>())
       builder.RegisterControllers(assembly).InstancePerHttpRequest();
       builder.RegisterApiControllers(assembly);
       builder.RegisterModelBinders(assembly).InstancePerHttpRequest();
       builder.RegisterType<LogAttribute>().PropertiesAutowired();
       builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

       // Needed to allow property injection in custom action filters.
       builder.RegisterType<ExtensibleActionInvoker>().As<IActionInvoker>();
       builder.RegisterControllers(assembly).InjectActionInvoker();
```

When I've made these changes however, two things happen:

Firstly, the default azure mobile app default helper page disappears and I get a default page with this:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Secondly, when I attempt to call the Help pages or AccountsController directly, a runtime exception is raised:

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
HResult=-2146233079
Message=No service registered for type 'ITableControllerConfigProvider'.Please ensure that the dependency resolver has been configured correctly.
Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service
StackTrace:
  at System.Web.Http.DependencyScopeExtensions.GetServiceOrThrow[TService](IDependencyScope services)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Tables.TableControllerConfigAttribute.Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.InvokeAttributesOnControllerType(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type type)
  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor..ctor(HttpConfiguration configuration, String controllerName, Type controllerType)
  at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.InitializeControllerInfoCache()
  at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
  at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
  at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
  at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector.GetControllerMapping()
  at System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.InitializeApiDescriptions()
  at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
  at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
  at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
  at System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.get_ApiDescriptions()
  at MyMobileApp.Mvc.Areas.HelpPage.Controllers.HelpController.Index() in C:\tfs\MyMobileApp\dotNET\Web\MyMobileApp.Mvc\Areas\HelpPage\Controllers\HelpController.cs:line 31
InnerException:
```

Does anyone know what the problem with this could be? Do I need to explicitly register the mobile service assemblies and if so, what's the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved.

Just to wrap this up, the basic problem was that I'd changed the WebApiConfig.Register method so that it was non standard.  I'd changed it from this

```
public static void Register()
```

to this

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
```

and was attempting to use it like one would a standard Mvc webapi configuration from Global.asax.cs

Once I changed it back, I was able to register objects using autofac in the method like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
builder.Register(c => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(c.Resolve<ApplicationContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).As<IAuthenticationManager>();
builder.Register(c => new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>
{
DataProtectionProvider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.DpapiDataProtectionProvider("Application​")
});
```

without any problem

thanks